# (CISCO Packet Tracer) Overlap Error

Tags: ip, ipv4, subnet, ip-address, packet-tracer

I am trying to set up a network of for different organisational departments based on a given typology:

[image: Given Typology]

Using Cisco 2911 routers & 2960-24TT Switches.

With given addressing of:

```
'EIGRP 101' 172.16.16.0 /16
and
'OSPF 2018' Addressing of 192.168.17.0 /24
```

from this I created a network addressing scheme:
[image: Addressing Scheme]

Using my addressing scheme and based on the given typology - I have attempted to recreate in Packet Tracer the network here:
[image: Created Typology]

As you can see in the top left 'Management' department subnet I have managed to set up Router0 through the Gi0/2 interface using the router's CLI. However, using my addressing scheme, I was unable to set up the same router for the 'Engineering' department through Router0's Gi0/1 interface due to a 'overlap' error:

```
Press RETURN to get started!

Router>en Router#conf terminal  Enter configuration commands, one per
line.  End with CNTL/Z. 
Router(config)#interface gigabitEthernet 0/2 
Router(config-if)#ip address 172.16.16.1 255.255.0.0
Router(config-if)#no shutdown 

Router(config-if)#
%LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface GigabitEthernet0/2, changed state to up

%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/2, changed 
state to up

Router(config-if)#do wr
Building configuration...
[OK]
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface gigabitEthernet 0/1
Router(config-if)#ip address 172.16.16.65 255.255.0.0
% 172.16.0.0 overlaps with GigabitEthernet0/2
Router(config-if)#
```

Is my addressing scheme wrong? Or am I using the Packet Tracer or the routers CLI incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your networks are part of the same network. Look at your network mask. If you mask the `172.16.x.x` addresses with the `255.255.0.0` mask you have assigned, you will see that all those networks are the same network. The same thing applies to the `192.168.17.x` network and its `255.255.255.0` mask.

Routers route packets between networks, not from a network back to the same network, so each router interface must be in a different network, but you are assigning the same network to multiple router interfaces, and that will generate an error.

---

You need to understand IPv4 network math. See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for an explanation of IPv4 address manipulation and subnetting.

---

Also, EIGRP and OSPF will not share routes unless you redistribute routes between them, and you would need a router that runs both protocols to do that. Routing protocols do not route, they exchange route information between routers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94652/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-maupin-cisco-packet-tracer-overlap-error).

Answer (score -1):

its because the two department are on the same network of 0.0 255.255.0.0. Put the two interface router linking management and engineering on different network and do a route.